# Finding the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2 \ln x}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to find the following limit:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2 \ln x}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$$

Even though when I evaluate the limit on the path $y = 0$, I get $0$ (which is the textbook's answer), that still doesn't prove that the limit exists.

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2 \ln x}{(x-1)^2 + y^2} \stackrel{y = 0}{=} \lim_{x \to 1} \ \ln x = 0
$$

I've thought about using $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ but quickly abandoned the idea (it's not gonna get me anywhere).

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: try $x'=x-1$ then change variable r and $\theta$

Comment: @Isham can I please ask you to elaborate? These limits are tricky...

Comment: Gimusi has posted a complete answer...if you substitute $x'=x-1$ then x' tend to 0 ...then substitute trig $( x'=r\cos(\theta)) $and $ y=r\sin(\theta))$  as you wanted to do in the first place

Comment: @Isham thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let set $u=x-1$ and $v=y$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (1,0)} \frac{(x-1)^2 \ln x}{(x-1)^2 + y^2}=\displaystyle \lim_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac{u^2 \ln (u+1)}{u^2 + v^2}=\cos^2\theta\,\ln(r\cos\theta+1)\to 0$$

indeed by squeeze theorem

$$0\le |\cos^2\theta\,\ln(r\cos\theta+1)|\le |\ln(r\cos\theta+1)| \to 0$$

Comment: I posted the same answer +1

Comment: @Isham oh yes I see! that's a good one way;)

Comment: @gimusi I don't follow the last step: if we use $r$ and $\theta$, $r$ goes to $0^+$ but what does $\theta$ go to?

Comment: @bru1987 You easily conclude by squeeze theorem, I add this step!

Comment: @gimusi thank you, got it!

Comment: @bru1987 Well done! You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
If $(x,y)\ne (1,0)$, one has
$$0\le\Biggl\lvert\frac{(x-1)^2\ln x}{(x-1)^2+y^2}\Biggr\rvert\le \lvert\ln x\rvert.$$

Comment: that's a nice way too!

Answer (score 1):

For $x\neq1$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \left|\frac{(x-1)^{2}\ln x}{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\\
 & \leq & \left|\frac{(x-1)^{2}\ln x}{(x-1)^{2}}\right|\\
 & = & \left|\ln x\right|.
\end{eqnarray*}
If $x=1$ and $y\neq0$, we have $\left|\frac{(x-1)^{2}\ln x}{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}\right|=0=\left|\ln x\right|$.
Hence, for any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(1,0)\}$, $\left|\frac{(x-1)^{2}\ln x}{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\leq\left|\ln x\right|.$
By Sandwich Rule, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)}\frac{(x-1)^{2}\ln x}{(x-1)^{2}+y^{2}}=0$
because $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(1,0)}\left|\ln x\right|=0$.